# How to pass variable in angular 4 as an argument?

Tags: angular

I have a div element in my HTML like so

```
<div (click) = onPaginationClick() *ngFor="let section of sections">next</div>
```

My question is : How to pass a variable to the onPaginationlick() function ? when I try to pass it like this :

```
<div (click)=onPaginationClick({{section.id}}) *ngFor="let section of sections">next</div>
```

I'm getting a parse template error.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `(...)` and `{{...}}` together:

```typescript
(click)="onPaginationClick(section.id)"
```